# Drawable not showing up when drawn on Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-drawable

I'm building an app which needs to draw a grid, and add images to various cells. There are about 10 different images, all in .png format. There's an array which allows the app to loop over each grid square and check whether that square should have an image, and if so, which one. If there's supposed to be an image in the square, it's drawn in as follows:

```
    for (int rr = 0; rr < numRows; rr++) {

        for (int cc = 0; cc < numCols; cc++) {

            // Find out what should be in this grid square
            CellImage thisCellImage = mChart.returnCellImage(rr,cc);

            if(thisCellImage == null) continue;

            // Find the drawable from the baseName
            String drawableName = thisCellImage.getName();
            Resources resources = mContext.getResources();
            int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(drawableName,
                            "drawable",
                            mContext.getPackageName());
            Drawable d;

            if(resourceId != 0) {
              if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                 d = resources.getDrawable(resourceId, mContext.getTheme());
               } else {
                 d = resources.getDrawable(resourceId);
               }

               // Calculate the position of the top left grid square
               float posX = minX + ((numCols - cc - 1) * cell_width);
               float posY = minY + ((numRows - rr - 1) * cell_height);

               // Now draw the image into the square
               if (d != null) {
                  d.setBounds(Math.round(posX), Math.round(posY),
                               Math.round(posX + cell_width),
                               Math.round(posY + cell_height));
                  d.draw(canvas);
               }
            }
        }
     }
```

The problem is that nothing is appearing on the grid. I can see from the debugger that the drawable has been found ok; the values calculated for posX and posY look reasonable (they are definitely within the grid, so even if they're not completely accurate, the drawable should be visible somewhere).

The grid has had a background colour added earlier, using:

```
mPaint.setColor(bgColour.returnHexCode());
canvas.drawRect(minX, minY, maxX, maxY, mPaint);
```

I've tried taking that step out (in case the background was hiding the drawable or something, but it didn't make any difference; I'm just including it here in case it might be relevant.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? I don't really know where to start with drawables.

### Edit

`CellImage` is defined as follows:

```
public class CellImage {

    private String name, description;

    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public CellImage() {}

    // GETTERS
    public String getName()         { return name; }
    public String getDescription()  { return description; }

    // SETTERS
    public void setName(String thisName)            { this.name = thisName; }
    public void setDescription(String thisDesc)     { this.description = thisDesc; }

}
```

The name of the `CellImage` is the same as the drawable file name.  Eg if the `CellImage` name is "example", then the drawable would be "example.png".

An example of a drawable is:
[image: circle.png drawable]

(most of the images are a bit more complicated than this one, so I can't just, eg, draw circles directly.  They are all saved as 64px x 64px pngs)

Comment: I just copy-pasted your code into a custom View and changed it a little bit (for me, mChart is just an int[][] with R.drawable.whatever resource ids). The grid gets drawn (I just used the default launcher foreground which is generated by Android Studio under res/drawable-v24). So I think maybe it's your specific drawable which is causing the issue. Try to have it drawn "standalone" - does that work?

Comment: Yes, it draws fine in other parts of the app. The drawing process is slightly different in the other parts, though - one is an adapter view (listing all the possible images), and the other is an ImageButton, which highlights the currently-selected image, so neither involves drawing onto a canvas.

Comment: Can you provide a drawable and the code for the CellImage class and any other relevant custom classes?

Comment: I've edited my original post to include the CellImage class and an example of one of my drawables. I don't think any of the other Classes are relevant (mChart is from the Chart class, but all it's doing here is returning a CellImage (which returns correctly, as I can see in the debugger)).

Comment: Unfortunately this drawable gets drawn in my sample as well. So I'm not able to reproduce your problem by setting up my own custom View. Now I know it will take some time to post a [MCVE] but without it I'm not able to help you. If you choose to do so I'd also like to know which buildToolsVersion/ targetSDK / android version (for the emulator) etc. you are using

Comment: Thank you for your help... It has started working! I think it was drawing it in white, for some reason - I happened to try adjusting the background, to work on something else, and the image showed up! Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know :) And good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that the image was drawing in white on a white background... I'll leave the question here in case it saves anyone else a few wasted hours.